# material dialog not rendering component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<p>I am a simple component</p>',
})
```

If I put `<my-component></my-component>` somewhere in my app's html, then as expected, I see the text: "I am a simple component" ...

However, using material dialog...

```
...

  openDialog () {
    this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, { data: { some: 'data' } });
  }

...    


@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: '<my-component></my-component>',
})
class ModalComponent {
  constructor (
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}
}
```

When I open this dialog, I get a blank dialog box.  And inspecting the HTML, I am basically seeing:

```
<mat-dialog-container ...(lots of attrs)>
  <modal>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </modal>
</mat-dialog-container>
```

Why is `my-component` not rendering in this context?

Comment: are you importing the material dialog module? Here is an example of how the slider module works, https://v9.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started, you need to load in the MatSliderModule for the slider to work.

Comment: @Sprep yes, the material dialog works fine, it's my custom component that does not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to stackBlitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmrbx5?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.html

In this example a component renders in dialog.

Import your my-component stuff into your app.module file.

I hope this is what you mean?

[image]

Here is an updated link, add all your components you want to shared module for you situation, make sure you are exporting them correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmrbx5-pipswr?file=src/app/shared-module.ts

[image]

Comment: Hmm..  Yeah I am doing this-- though slightly differently: I have a `shared.module` which my app module imports, and the shared module has both `MaterialModule` and my custom component in the declarations array...

Comment: Ok I have updated it with a new stackblitz, there is shared modules. I cant do it exactly as how you have (would be nice is you could show a basic example) but the update in my answer has a dialog with component via a share module.

Comment: Would be nice to know if any of the effort I put in helped you.

Comment: Sorry, yeah-- I have been trying to figure out the difference and I can't find very much...  The only other major difference is this is a hybrid application, and I did try downgrading my custom component, but for whatever reason it still will not render this component...  very frustrating.

Comment: Can you set up a stackblitz?

Comment: I got it figured out..  I was not putting the component the dialog was opening in `declarations`, which was what was so confusing to me because the template for THAT component was rendering-- just not the child component `my-component` within it..  Still doesn't make sense to me, but whatever at least it works.

Comment: great stuff, I did make a little red stripe for declarations, its always some little thing :) Glad you got it worked out.